# How can I add up all the values in a listbox?

Tags: c#

I have a listbox, with an unspecified amount of values.
They will all be a decimal converted to a string eg

```
21.10
32.50
43.49
42.00
```

I then want to add these all up and display them in a textbox, how would I go about this?

My guess is I will first need to convert them all from ListItem back to a decimal, for however many times there is an item. I have no idea how to go about this though

This is what i tried(from an oldpost here)

```
decimal total = (from string S in Listbox.Items select Convert.ToDecimal(S)).Sum();
```

Received This Error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to
>   type 'System.String'.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code that you have tried first.. Basically, you want to get sum of all these decimal values represented as strings in your `ListBox` right?

Comment: Try to reduce your problem to the single steps. For example, one step in your problem is *reading an item value from a list box and interpreting it as a number*, another step is *computing the sum from a list of numbers*.

Comment: Updated the original post with one of the ways I tried.
And Thanks O.R Mapper for your tips :)

Comment: How are you getting the values into the listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was bugged.

Corrected:

```
decimal total = (from item in listbox.Items.Cast<ListItem>() select Convert.ToDecimal(item.Value)).Sum();
```

Comment: Thanks however I get "The contextual keyword 'var' cannot be used in a range variable declaration"
"

Comment: Another error unfortunately "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'item'" Thanks very much for all your help though!

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var s = lb.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Sum<ListItem>(p=>Convert.ToDecimal(p.Value));
```

Comment: Error 4 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Sum<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,int>>)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
  double sum=0; //var to store the sum of items

    foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
    {
       sum=sum+double.Parse(s); // in each iteration we parse the string value of listbox to double and add it to current sum
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but Error 3 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' because 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Adding some explanation along with the code would make this answer better.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
foreach(var item in listBox.Items)
{
   sum + = convert.ToDecimal(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create textbox `txtAddNumbers` , listBox `lstNumbers` , button `btnAdd` , label `lblSum`.

Code of Button `btnAdd` click-

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(txtAddNumbers.Text);
        txtAddNumbers.Clear();


        int iList = 0, result = 0;
        while (iList < lstNumbers.Items.Count)
        {
            result += Convert.ToInt32(lstNumbers.Items[iList++]);
        }

        lblSum.Text = "Sum : " + Convert.ToString((double)result);   

        //you can also calculate Average
        lblMean.Text = "Mean : " + Convert.ToString((double)result / iList);

    }
```